# How do i increment a global variable in a function in java script from a button?

Tags: javascript, html

this might be a dumb thing to ask but I am getting a lot of trouble with this for and quiz I need to make for and assignment, and I am trying to increment the score when the user clicks to the correct button. However, the score is not incrementing. here is a little sample of what it looks like.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <title>Increment Button</title>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="IncrementScore()"> Increment</button>

<script>
 var score = 0;
 
 function IncrementScore()
 {
  score++;
 }
 
 console.log(score);
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: have your tried `score += 1`?

Comment: Why are you setting `score` back to `1` after you increment it?

Comment: yes, I have and it's not working either.

Comment: `console.log(score)` should be inside the function.

Comment: Was `score = 1` causing the problem, or was that a typo of some sort? If the former, you shouldn't remove it from the question.

Comment: yes, `score = 1` was something I was trying out and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. You probably want to `console.log` from within the `IncrementScore` function.
2. You want to increment the variable using `+= 1` or `++`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="IncrementScore()"> Increment</button>

  <script>
    var score = 0;

    function IncrementScore() {
      score++;
      console.log(score);
    }

    console.log(score);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On each click you increment variable. And in next line assign to variable "1". You should delete line

```
score = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to `score += 1` and move you console call to inside of your function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <title>Increment Button</title>
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="IncrementScore()"> Increment</button>

<script>
 var score = 0;
 
 function IncrementScore()
 {
  
  score += 1;
    console.log(score);
 }
 
 console.log(score);
</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Why should he change `score++` to `score += 1`? They're essentially the same.

Comment: Please do not post code to 3rd party sites, like Fiddles or CodePens as these links can die over time and make your answer meaningless. Post your code right here in your answer as a code snippet.(use the `<>` button while composing your answer).

Comment: @ScottMarcus I did not know that. Thanks for the info

Comment: @Barmar just showing OP that there are different ways to get the result he wants.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Actually the `score` **did** increment, **but not be printed out** via the click handler.

As I know in your snippet, all your script in `<script>` tag (include `console.log`) will **all execute once initially**. Then it **sits there to listen to the events**, like your click. Then when you click on the button, the `IncrementScore` function is called, it increments the `score` variable, but not print it out. You know why? because you don't tell it to do so, **(in the `IncrementScore` handler)**. If you notice, you'll see that you only have one `0` printed out, not each `0` per click.

You should read about *the call stack*,etc.. to know more about the order which code is executed...
The fixes snippet can be found in other's answer, here is the code for when the variable actually "does not change", and be printed out for each click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="IncrementScore()"> Increment</button>

<script>
  var score = 0;
  function IncrementScore()  {
    //score++;
    console.log(score);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh, I understand what you mean. However now in my actual code, i fixed it up but getting another problem. i see the results changing in the console but it flashes and disappears

Comment: @JosiahFrancis oh, where is your "actual code", did you show it?

Comment: no, i did not show it but i solved the problem i did something silly which was causing the problem.